# iOS: Find keys in Localizable.strings that were never used

Tags: ios, xcode

In Xcode (iOS), is there a macro or some other way to check the Localizable.strings file and find keys that were created but never used in code? Over time I know that we've created some strings that ended up not being used and it would be great to clean up the file for the translators.